# Grails - Batik.jar interaction

Tags: grails, build, config, batik

An external Library need the Batik.jar Library.
But on Loading it outputs:
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of ) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/xml/sax/SAXParseException"

I tried modifying the build config.groovy file to exclude xml-apis but it didnt work. Any workaround for using batik?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem , I've manually looked for all `ivy*.xml` files in  `%User%\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.xmlgraphics` and deleted the following entry :

```
<dependency org="xml-apis" name="xml-apis" rev="1.3.04" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the selenium libraries, which have contain some xml-libraries. I extracted these newer/outdated versions from *selenium* and then it worked.

I had a look into "batik" and in the lib folder there are xalan, xerces and xml-apis. Try to remove them and hope, that the api-versions provided from grails are compatible.